# Simulating loss of broker publisher connectivity in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

I wish to run an experiment in which the publisher loses connection with the broker and then enqueues messages in its own queue and then when it regains connectivity it sends all its queued messages to the broker. How can I I do this since if I call close connection, I can no longer send(raises an exception). A trick that I can think of is to use a network of two brokers and simulate the above by breaking the connection between the two brokers. Is there an API call that I can use to do the above?

This is very much like facebook messenger or whatsapp acting as a publisher and enqueuing our to-send messages if we are offline and sending them once we are connected.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of solutions you could use to break the connection in order to test, here is a non-comprehensive list :

- Make a script that can set/unset a firewall rule on your environement blocking the connection port
- If you are working with VMs, you can suspend/resume the one running Activemq, you can even automate it with tools like vagrant (vagrant suspend, then vagrant up)
- Tweak the connection manualy accessing the activemq jmx
- Develop an activemq plugin able to trash connections on demand (or maybe there is one ?)

Now in order to have the behavior you wish to obtain there is two options :

1) Make sure your connection is failover so it can be reestablished, and store your message on disk before sending them with your producer.

2)Produce to a local broker embbeded in your app, and connect this one to the remote broker.

Comment: You seem to suggest ways to close a connection. If I do that, send no longer works as connection is broken. I wish to keep sending and have messages queued in an internal structure of the producer.